# Magento 1.9 Use Base Currency To Checkout On Payment Gateway

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, payment-gateway, multicurrency

I have a multi-currency website (MYR & USD) while MYR is the primary currency, When a user try to purchase i want to pass the value in MYR to the payment gateway since  it supports on MYR, below my code in redirect.phtml, Is there any way i can fix this. TIA

```
<?php
// Retrieve order

$order = $this->getOrder();
$_helper = Mage::helper('managepay');
$phone = substr(str_replace(' ', '', $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone()), 0, 20);
?>
<div><span>You will be redirected to the Manage Pay website in a few seconds.</span></div>
<form name="managepay_form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_helper->getGatewayUrl() ?>">
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Submit')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Click here if you are not redirected within 10 seconds...') ?></span></span></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="secureHash" value="<?php echo $_helper->secureHash() ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<?php echo $_helper->getMerchantId() ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="invno" value="<?php echo $_helper->getInvoiceNo() ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="amt" value="<?php echo $_helper->getAmount() ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDesc() ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="postURL" value="<?php echo $this->getResponseUrl()  ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone ?>"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $order->getCustomerEmail(); ?>"><br>
<!--    <input type="hidden" name="param" value="47630|P123"><br>-->
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.managepay_form.submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is been fix my declaring getAmount() value to be set as BaseGrandTotal inside 
/app/code/local/Magebuzz/paymentgateway/Helper/Data.php

```
   public function getAmount()
    {
        $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
        $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        return $order->getBaseGrandTotal() * 100;
    }
```